# SQLITE bulk inserts to increase optimization with UPDATE and INSERT

Tags: android, mysql, sql, performance, sqlite

I have seen a lot of posts on optimizing SQLITE on android with bulk inserts
Currently its taking 90 seconds to do 900 inserts/updates.  I added the Begin/End Transaction around them but only saw minor improvements. 
So I want to add I believe SQLiteStatement

Here is my code currently

```
static ArrayList<ContentSystem> csList = new ArrayList<ContentSystem>();
```

..fill out csList..

```
_dh.BeginTransaction(Table);
for(int i = 0; i < csList.size(); ++i)
{
    addItem(ma, csList.get(i), dh, Table, Key);
}
_dh.setTransactionSuccessful();
_dh.EndTransaction(Table);

public static void addItem(final MainActivity ma, ContentSystem cs,
final DatabaseHandler dh, String Table, String Key) 
{
         worked = dh.UpdateItem(cs.cv, Table, Key, cs.UUID);
         if (worked == 0) 
         {
            worked = dh.AddData(Table, cs.cv);
            if (worked <= 0) 
            {
               ErrorLogger.AddError("Error") 
            }
         }
}
```

My problem is that if my csList contains ~1000 items and some are already in my list, some are not
so I am currently doing a update if the update returns 0 then I do an add

How could I get something like this to work in a bulk statement?

A bit more info

dh.Update

```
int wok = db.update(table, values, Key + " = ?", new String[] { Item });
```

dh.Add

```
int work = (int) db.insert(table, null, values);
```

ContentSystem is a list of ContentValues

Comment: Refer to this thread, it's incredible - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1711631/how-do-i-improve-the-performance-of-sqlite

Comment: @bclymer Yes - that is one of the ones I have been using - I don't understand how do do multiple types of queries in a bulk transaction - I know I need to do them - which is in a nutshell what that shows

Comment: I'm surprised that thread was available to you guys since the question was closed.  In any event, since my reputation is unjustifiably high, I voted to re-open it.  Perhaps others will do so as well.

Comment: @DanBracuk Not sure what your talking about... The link that bclymer provided has been protected - in any event I am trying to get help on the matter at hand.. Thanks

Comment: I just clicked on the link and the title was "How do I improve the performance of SQLite? [closed]".  The closure reason was that it was not clear what was being asked.  That's true, but I voted to re-open it anyway.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Try `INSERT OR REPLACE`](http://www.sqlite.org/lang_insert.html), instead of either just an update or a failed update followed by an insert.

Comment: @morty what results did you find with this?

Answer (score 0):

Are you sure the instantiated SQLiteDatabase object in your DatabaseHandler class is the same as `_dh`?

You might have started a transaction for _dh, but that might not even be the instantiated object that is actually doing any work.

Comment: This is a section for answers - 
The code works fine as is (albeit room for improvement)- this is an optimization question to change my code to use prepared statements and bulk transactions - also the database system is single threaded and yes _dh is the cored sqlitedatabase object